# Trying to use st.multiselect() in streamlit app not getting desired results

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, plotly, streamlit

I am trying to make a data app with multiselect for visualizing data. I want to show a grouped bar chart with three parameters for the clients selected in the multiselect option. However, No matter whichever client I select the graph is shown in the same order as the original data i.e even if I select the 7th client in the multiselect, I still get the graph for the first row in the data frame.
Here’s the code:

```
data = load_data()

st.markdown('### Client Selection, Offers and Joinings')
clients= data['Client']
clients1=clients.to_list()
options=st.multiselect('Client List',clients1)
st.write(data)

selections=data['selections'] 
offers=data['offers']
joinings=data['joinings']

fig1 = go.Figure()
fig1.add_trace(go.Bar(
    x=options,
    y=selections,
    name='Selections',
    marker_color='indianred'
))
fig1.add_trace(go.Bar(
   x=options,
   y=offers,
   name='Offers',
    marker_color='lightsalmon'
))
fig1.add_trace(go.Bar(
   x=options,
   y=joinings,
   name='joinings',
    marker_color='indianred'
))

# Here we modify the tickangle of the xaxis, resulting in rotated labels.
fig1.update_layout(barmode='group', xaxis_tickangle=-45)
st.plotly_chart(fig1)
```

Can someone please help me with this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the slicing of the dataframe, the correct way is:

```
data1 = load_data()

st.markdown('### Client Selection, Offers and Joinings')
clients= data1['Client']
clients1=clients.copy().to_list() 
options=st.multiselect('Client List',clients1)
st.write(data1)

if not options:
    filtered_data = data1.copy()
else:
    filtered_data = data1.loc[data1["Client"].isin(options)]

st.dataframe(filtered_data, width=1000, height=500)

selections=filtered_data['selections'] 
offers=filtered_data['offers']
joinings=filtered_data['joinings']
```